# Sync doesn't appear to be working on Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, sync

Asked on the Mozilla forum about a week ago and no response there. So I'll try here:

I just made the switch from Chrome to Firefox on desktop and mobile. But either Firefox syncing isn’t working or I don’t understand how it’s supposed to work. On both browsers I have cleared history and opened up two different sets of URLS. Signed into both browsers with the same credentials. Desktop has URLs ABC etc and Mobile has URLs XYZ etc. I expect that when I manually sync on both devices, both sets of URLs should show up in History on both devices. But nothing showing on one device from the other device Also, on mobile it says sync complete as of this many hours ago, yet I see no content from desktop. And on desktop, it says sync complete yet no desktop history shown on the mobile browser. What gives?

Comment: what have you enabled in "choose what to sync"? can you see both devices in "manage account" -> connected services?

Comment: Everything looks good so far: Choose What to Sync Desktop: Syncing Bookmarks, History, Open tabs, Logins and passwords, Add-ons, Settings (everything except addresses and credit cards)
Choose What to Sync Mobile: Syncing Bookmarks, History, Logins, Open Tabs (everything except credit cards)
Connected Services: Both desktop and mobile show up as connected services (seen when looking at desktop browser)

Comment: does *Everything looks good so far* mean it works as required now?

Comment: No, I meant the settings look good as per your note. But still nothing is syncing.

Comment: As you have correctly surmised, Firefox Sync very often does absolutely nothing at all. I've battled this numerous times, it's been all over their support forums for years. The solution is to either go without syncing or switch to a working browser. I can't believe how far Mozilla has fallen.

Comment: ok, so it's not just me... thanks JS